# Can you say that associative arrays in PHP are like 2D arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Can you say that associative arrays in PHP are like 2D arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D array is more like a matrix, a plane, a coordinate system. An associative array on the other hand could be called a dictionary or hash.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are still one-dimensional just like regular 0-based arrays. The difference is that you aren't limited to integers for the keys; you can use any arbitrary string.

And strictly speaking there isn't a technical distinction between associative and non-associative arrays. They use the same syntax, it's just your choice whether you use integers or strings or both for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var[$x] = 1-dimensional
$var[$y][$y2] = 2-dimensional
$var[$z][$z2][$z3] = 3-dimensional
```

It doesn't matter if $x, $y or $z are numeric or strings, actually.

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia
**Associative array**

> An associative array (also associative
>   container, map, mapping, dictionary,
>   finite map, and in query-processing an
>   index or index file) is an abstract
>   data type composed of a collection of
>   unique keys and a collection of
>   values, where each key is associated
>   with one value (or set of values).

So an associative array is actually an ADT, implemented in another way.
Instead, a 2d array "really" has two dimensions and is, usually, a primitive type.